# When adding text to mouse location on click giving segmentation fault

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to write a code for a program where when the user clicks on the image at the clicked location I should display its RGB values.

I have looked through documentation of OpenCV and found that putText function will help me to achieve my desired results. I wrote the code following the documentation in OpenCV.

Here is my code

```
cv::Mat img;
void mouse_Callback(int event , int x , int y , int flag ,void *params)
{
    if(event == cv::EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        cv::Vec3b vec = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(x,y);
        int b,g,r;
        b = (int)vec(0);
        g = (int)vec(1);
        r = (int)vec(2);

        cv::String st = to_string(b);
        cout << b << endl;
        cv::putText(img,st,cv::Point2i(x,y),cv::FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.8, cvScalar(255,100,250), 1, CV_AA);

        cv::imshow("image",img);
    }
}

int main()
{
    cv::namedWindow("image",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    img = cv::imread("1.jpg",-1);

    cv::setMouseCallback("image",mouse_Callback);

    cv::imshow("image",img);

    char key = cv::waitKey(0);
    if(key==27)
    {
        cv::destroyAllWindows();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After running the code for the first two or three clicks I am getting correct output after that I am getting a segmentation fault.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What exactly is the error? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that you don't get a segmentation fault, but rather a "normal" assertion error. I ran your code, and noticed, you use `cv::Vec3b vec = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)` in your callback. Change that to `cv::Vec3b vec = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x)` (`x` and `y` are switched), and you should be fine.

Comment: It works @HansHirse !! I have been wasting my time on this error since morning. In my laptop, it is showing segmentation fault I don't know why. Thank you !!!

Comment: I transferred my comment to an answer, because this is a common mistake, and people might come across your question looking for help. So, I would kindly ask you to accept my below answer, so that future readers see, that your problem could be fixed in that way.

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem is located in the `mouse_Callback(...)` function, more specifically here:

```cpp
cv::Vec3b vec = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y);
```

Looking at the OpenCV documentation on the [`.at`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ac40425b84f60b39fd35e03814122661f) operator, we see, that the first parameter indicates the row index, and the second parameter the column index. Now, when you work with image coordinates `(x, y)`, e.g. fetched from a mouse click on an image, then `x` corresponds to the column index, and `y` to the row index!

So, the simple fix is just to switch `x` and `y`:

```cpp
cv::Vec3b vec = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x);
```